# Unable to select the ANT build file in the jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant

Im running Jenkins on Heroku, but I was not able to select the ANT Build file, It is only having the option to copy and paste the file, Please suggest. Also If I paste the file, while running the build it throws this error.
"ERROR: Unable to find build script at /app/.jenkins/workspace/Salesforce/"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see if you click on the `(?)` help icon next to the "Build File" field, you're meant to enter the Ant build file name here:

> If your build requires a custom [-buildfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options),
>     specify it here.  By default Ant will use the `build.xml` in the root directory;
>     this option can be used to use build files with a different name or in a subdirectory.